# jQuery JSON request not loading

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to using the jQuery JSON request method, and I have a feeling I am making a really silly mistake with it.

For some reason, the following is not being called. The alert box never opens, and the `html` variable never is populated.

Any Ideas?

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
                json = data;

                html = '<div class=' + id + '><div id=' + id + ' class="child" style="display:none;">';
                for (x in json[elementId].images) {
                    html += '<img src=\"' + json[elementId].images[x] + '\" />';
                }
                html += '</div></div>';
                alert(html);
            });
```

Thanks a lot,

Isaac

Comment: what's id?  where is it being populated?

Comment: `id` is a parameter passed to the parent function in which this $.getJSON lives.

Comment: is this served from a web server or file:/// ?

Comment: Web server... file:/// gets weird cross domain errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your Net tab in Firebug to see if the request is actually successful? You might be getting some sort of an error (connection failed or improperly-formatted JSON perhaps). Try converting the `jQuery.getJSON` into a `jQuery.ajax` with an error handler to see if you have errors:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.json', 
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    json = data;

    html = '<div class=' + id + '><div id=' + id + ' class="child" style="display:none;">';
    for (x in json[elementId].images) {
       html += '<img src=\"' + json[elementId].images[x] + '\" />';
    }
    html += '</div></div>';
    alert(html);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know